# Is there a valid reason to ignore null/invalid SSL certs (when dealing with payment processing)?

Tags: ssl, e-commerce, ssl-certificate, payment-processing

So I got this dll from UnionPay for an ecom project with China and was asked to review.  After throwing this into ILSpy, I couldn't help but notice the following method:

```
private static bool RemoteCertificateCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
     return true;
}
```

Now, as I understand it, the purpose of such a callback is to allow for invalid or null SSL certificates - I've added similar support myself for unit testing.

(This sort of thing makes me highly suspicious of CHR government intervention allowing for intentional man-in-the-middle monitoring of transactions.)

Is there any legitimate reason for a payment processor to support null/invalid certs?

Comment: As you mentioned, it's useful for debugging.  If they expect you to run this in production, get rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any legitimate reason for a payment processor to support
>   null/invalid certs?

None whatsoever. You are holding a secret conversion in a darkened room with ... anybody. You may as well be using plaintext. See the comments on non-authenticated SSL in [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt). I agree with @SLaks entirely.